# Empty extract result - Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I'm trying to scrape data using Scrapy and my json/csv is empty. It's not my first scraper and I really don't understand why this not working.

Here is my scraper.

```
import scrapy
import itertools
from ..items import NumItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import json 
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

class ColekaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract_test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.coleka.com/fr']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.coleka.com/fr/cartes-de-collection/cartes-pokemon/pokemon-epee-et-bouclier/voltage-eclatant/aspicot-reverse_i804899'
    ]

    
    def parse(self, response):
        items = NumItem()
        for k in response.xpath('//div[@class="bigTitle clearfix hasImg "]'):
            extract = k.xpath('//div[@class="darker"]').extract()
            items['extract'] = extract
            yield items
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you writing the items to a json document? Is it a pipeline for feed export? Please show the code of that part as well, if you have it. If you don't have a part that is exporting the data to a file, then you can't expect the file to populate just from `yield`.

Comment: I'm using windows command : scrapy crawl extract_test -o [file_name].json

Comment: Hmm then it should be working fine. Do you see the scraped output in the console?

Comment: I can show you the response from the console. I had put it in answer from my post but someone deleted it. It's surprising because it's not my first scraper and I always use the same program, modified for each website

Answer (score 0):

Here is my response command for harada, please do not delete them.

```
2020-12-15 14:57:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: coleka)
2020-12-15 14:57:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-12-15 14:57:56 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'coleka', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'test20.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'coleka.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['coleka.spiders']}
2020-12-15 14:57:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: c6c871dbada3c7f5
2020-12-15 14:57:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.coleka.com/fr/cartes-de-collection/cartes-pokemon/pokemon-epee-et-bouclier/voltage-eclatant/aspicot-reverse_i804899> (referer: None)
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 317,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 413,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.163562,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 13, 57, 57, 522702),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 13, 57, 57, 359140)}
2020-12-15 14:57:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have an idea of what will fix this issue. From the provided console logs, we see that it does successfully crawl to the desired page. However, no data is scraped. Consider [reading the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css) for why `response.css` is better in this situation (selecting by classes).

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = NumItem()
    # make sure the selectors are correct, let's use the logger to check what the selector gives us
    selector = response.css('div.bigTitle.clearfix.hasImg')
    self.logger.info(f'the selector: {selector}')
    for k in selector:
        # try debugging with the logger
        self.logger.info(f'k in the selector loop is: {k}')
        extract = k.css('div.darker').getall() # getall is synonymous to extract
        items['extract'] = extract
        yield items
```

Hopefully this will help you find why the data is not being yielded and written to your file. If the logger shows nothing, for the selector and k, then you know your selector is wrong and is not finding anything on the page.

Comment: So, i've tried with the selector and it works fine with an other website. So yes, the selector is wrong and is not finding anything on the page i'm trying to scrape. 
Now the question is about the HTML page. It seems to be a massive table / tr / td. Can the problem comes from there ?